# what should be the good normalization for the following scenario?

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization

**ITS JUST FAKE TABLE DATA TO SIMPLIFY MY PROBLEM**

I have tables ,,  Users , shirts, pants, belts .... each will have some data...

so by some research i have made some scenarios of links between the tables so what would be the Optimized and very good ..

**Scenario 1**

I will have tables

1. user_shirts  ( user_shirt_id (PK), user_id(FK), shirt_id(FK))
2. user_shirts_pants  (user_shirts_pants_id (PK), user_shirt_id (Fk),  pant_id(FK))
3. user_shirts_pants_belts (user_shirts_pants_belts_id(PK) , user_shirts_pants_id (Fk), belt_id (Fk))

If there is

users(1)
Shirts ( A, B)
pants (a,b,c)
belts(I,II)

there will be 1 row in users table...
there will be 2 rows in users_shirts table...
there will be 6 rows in user_shirts_pants table...
there will be 12 rows in user_shirts_pants_belts  table....

then this will have data

**Scenario 2**

I will have tables

1. user_shirts_pants_belts (user_shirts_pants_belts_id(PK) , user_id(FK), shirts_id (Fk),  pant_id(FK), belt_id (Fk))

users(1)
Shirts ( A, B)
pants (a,b,c)
belts(I,II)

- there is 1 row in users table
  -there will be 12 rows in user_shirts_pants_belts  table....

**So which scenario is good.. and in normalization form... i should adopt whi9ch scenarion... if any better scenario then this then suggest me...? So i can make more and more relational combination and i easily update and delete them... **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is it we are trying to get to here? Do you want to list out all the outfits (combinations of shirts, belts, and pants) a user can wear? Or just what they have worn for a particular day? Sorry, I'm not following the needs for the three relational tables (user_shirts, user_shirts_pants, user_shirts_pants_belts).

I would just have one table for each item (with pkid and description of item), then a table that has a separate foreign key to those item tables:

users (id int, name varchar(100))
shirts (id int, desc varchar(100))
pants (id int, desc varchar(100))
belts (id int, desc varchar(100))
user_outfits (id int, user_id int, shirt_id int, pant_id int, belt_id int, dt date)

Then you could enter any item they wore or null if they didn't wear that item.

Comment: my data structure is different than this example.... i just wanted to know ... my table will be normalized if i have ...   table like user_outfits... means i have table where will be shirt_id , pant_id and belt_id in the same table...

Comment: Because one of my friend said scenario 1 will be more normalized then scenario 2.... so scenario 2 is more normalized ...?